# Text started blinking after few minute in setInterval javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval

I am making a div that is changing it's text in every 10sec with the help of setInterval function.
It's working very well but after 5-6min it start changing it's text in millisecond so it is looking like it is blinking.

my code is:

```
var wordArray = ["TEXT1","TEXT2","TEXT3"];

function typingEffect() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    $("#big-bob h5").text(wordArray[rand]);
    $("#big-bob h5").addClass("animate");
    setInterval(typingEffect,10000);
}

typingEffect();
```

Comment: This is happening because the a new setInterval is being added each time the function is called. Either use clearInterterval or change the setInterval to  setTimeout. Note the differences: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new interval everytime you execute the `typingEffect()` function...

```
var wordArray = ["TEXT1","TEXT2","TEXT3"];

function typingEffect() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    $("#big-bob h5").text(wordArray[rand]).addClass("animate");
}

setInterval(typingEffect,10000);
typingEffect(); // This last line is only needed if you want to execute the function
                // when page loads (otherwise, first execution will be after the
                // first 10 seconds)
```

To do it in your way, you should use `setTimeout()`...

```
var wordArray = ["TEXT1","TEXT2","TEXT3"];

function typingEffect() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    $("#big-bob h5").text(wordArray[rand]).addClass("animate");
    setTimeout(typingEffect,10000);
}

typingEffect();
```

Comment: Hi A. Lglesias Thanks alot. this is working very well. But i need some more information. the timing in this function is 10s and on the animation(css) it is also 10s but both not matching each other.

Comment: Yes, timers can suffer delays depending on the CPU load, etc. (Web browsers, like all applications, take turns for a piece of CPU time, and the time they have to wait will vary, depending on the load). You should set a `setTimeout` interval duration bigger than the css animation, to be sure that the css animation has enough time to complete before the next `setInterval` iteration arrives. Probably 1 second of difference should be enough, but try different values to adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Hi A. Lglesias, Thanks again. Now i got a problem again. Actually i don't want random string. I want step by step string through the array wordArray. Help me please.

Comment: Show what have you tried and what problem do you have  I’ll give you hand

Comment: my website is not live that's why i can't show you. But my problem is that wordArray have text1,text2,text3 and typingEffect() function changing text from h5 tag. But it changing text randomly like sometime text1 changing to text1 not to text2. And i want to change it step by step mean first TEXT1, again TEXT2 again TEXT3 again TEXT1 continuously.

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but this page is not a free coding service. You have to try to do it and in case you have a problem, you create a question showing the code you've created so far and what problem are you having, and we'll try help you. But this can't be "I want to do this... do it for me".